# Consumer queue remove even though cachelevel is set to CACHE_CONSUMER

Tags: apache-camel

I realized, even after explicitly setting the property

```
<property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER"/>
```

my consumer is still removed.

See log below:

```
23:14:25,180 | Usage | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 |     Main:memory:queue://reply:memory: usage change from: 0% of available memory, to: 1% of available memory
23:14:25,180 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | reply toPageIn: 1, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 2, enqueueCount: 2, dequeueCount: 1
23:14:25,180 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | reply toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 3, enqueueCount: 2, dequeueCount: 1
23:14:25,180 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | reply toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 3, enqueueCount: 2, dequeueCount: 1
23:14:25,649 | ActiveMQMessageConsumer | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | remove: ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-8:1:1:84, lastDeliveredSequenceId:0
23:14:25,649 | AbstractRegion | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core -     5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | default removing consumer: ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-8:1:1:84 for destination: queue://routerResponse
23:14:25,649 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | queue://routerResponse remove sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-8:1:1:84, destinations=1, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, lastDeliveredSeqId: 0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0
23:14:25,649 | AbstractRegion | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | default adding consumer: ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-8:1:1:85 for destination: queue://routerResponse
23:14:25,649 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | queue://routerResponse add sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-8:1:1:85, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0
23:14:26,165 | ActiveMQMessageConsumer | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | remove: ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-14:1:1:4, lastDeliveredSequenceId:0
23:14:26,165 | AbstractRegion | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | default removing consumer: ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-14:1:1:4 for destination: queue://reply
23:14:26,165 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | queue://reply remove sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-14:1:1:4, destinations=1, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, lastDeliveredSeqId: 0, dequeues: 1, dispatched: 1, inflight: 0
23:14:26,165 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | reply toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 3, enqueueCount: 2, dequeueCount: 1
23:14:26,165 | AbstractRegion | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | default adding consumer: ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-14:1:1:5 for destination: queue://reply
23:14:26,165 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | queue://reply add sub: QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-14:1:1:5, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 1, dispatched: 1, inflight: 0
23:14:26,165 | Queue | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | reply toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 3, enqueueCount: 2, dequeueCount: 1
23:14:26,649 | ActiveMQMessageConsumer | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.0.fuse-00-43 | remove: ID:TestESB-3364-1321307776420-8:1:1:85, lastDeliveredSequenceId:0
```

See my camel spring config below:

```
<bean id="providerConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<!--<property name="brokerURL"><value>${aero-provider-broker-url}</value></property>-->
```

```
<bean id="providerActiveMQConfig" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQConfiguration">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="providerConnectionFactory"/>
  <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER"/>
  <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms-concurrent-consumers}"/>
  <property name="requestTimeout" value="${jms-request-timeout}"/>
  <property name="priority" value="${jms-message-priority}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="providerActivemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="configuration" ref="providerActiveMQConfig"/>
  <property name="brokerURL"><value>${provider-broker-url}</value></property>
</bean>
```

Edit here >>>>

BEan definition:

```
   <bean id="localJMSConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="alwaysSessionAsync" value="false"/>
    <property name="alwaysSyncSend" value="true"/>
    <property name="brokerURL"><value>${local-broker-url}</value></property>
    <property name="closeTimeout" value="150000"/>
    <property name="copyMessageOnSend" value="true"/>
    <property name="disableTimeStampsByDefault" value="false"/>
    <property name="dispatchAsync" value="false"/>
    <property name="objectMessageSerializationDefered" value="false"/>
    <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="false"/>
    <property name="optimizedMessageDispatch" value="true"/>
    <property name="producerWindowSize" value="0"/>
    <property name="statsEnabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="false"/>
    <property name="useCompression" value="false"/>
    <property name="sendTimeout" value="0"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="localJMSTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="localJMSConnectionFactory" />               
</bean> 
<bean id="localRequestJMSConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="localJMSConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms-concurrent-consumers}"/>
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
    <property name="priority" value="9"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="localRequestJMS" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="localRequestJMSConfig"/>        
</bean>
```

Camel Enpoint Definition:

```
<camel:endpoint id="jmsEndpoint" camelContextId="bohProcessorCC" uri="localRequestJMS:queue:${boh-processor-queue}"/>

<camel:endpoint id="providerEndpoint" camelContextId="bohProcessorCC" uri="providerActivemq:queue:${generic-http-provider-queue}?exchangePattern=InOut&amp;requestTimeout=${jms-request-timeout}&amp;replyTo=reply"/>
```

Camel Route:

```
 <from ref="jmsEndpoint"/>
 <bean ref="service" method="getSignInRequest"/> 
 <transform><simple>XML=${in.body}</simple></transform> 
 <inOut ref="providerEndpoint"/> 
 <bean ref="service" method="getSignInResponseData"/>  
 <bean ref="utilityServicesBean" method="process"/> 
 <bean ref="service" method="getPassword"/> 
 <inOut ref="providerEndpoint"/> 
 <bean ref="camelPropertyEnricherBean" method="addCustReference"/> 
 <bean ref="camelPropertyEnricherBean" method="normalizeXML"/> 
 <inOut ref="providerEndpoint"/>
```

On the second  call, the exchange times out, usually saying timeout. Typically there is response on the reply queue but the log says correlation id doesnt match. I noticed that if I ask camel to set the message id as correlation id just before calling the provider endpoint, it usually returns with a message. Even that fails sometimes when there are high traffic.

Comment: Can you please include the routes? From what it looks like you're doing some sort of request-reply, but it's not clear.

Comment: <bean ref="service" method="getSignInRequest"/>  
<transform><simple>XML=${in.body}</simple></transform>  
<inOut ref="providerEndpoint"/>  
<bean ref="service" method="getSignInResponseData"/>  
<bean ref="utilityServicesBean" method="process"/>  
<bean ref="service" method="getPassword"/>  
<inOut ref="providerEndpoint"/>  
<bean ref="camelPropertyEnricherBean" method="addCustReference"/>  
<bean ref="camelPropertyEnricherBean" method="normalizeXML"/>  
<inOut ref="providerEndpoint"/>

Comment: <camel:endpoint id="providerEndpoint" camelContextId="bohProcessorCC" uri="providerActivemq:queue:${generic-http-provider-queue}?exchangePattern=InOut&amp;requestTimeout=${jms-request-timeout}&amp;replyTo=reply"/>

Comment: These look incomplete. Could you please edit them into the question along with the camelContext and from tags?

Comment: Could the problem be because I am re-using endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use request/reply over JMS with Camel, eg yo do an inOut ref="providerEndpoint", which also uses a fixed replyTo queue name, as you specify replyTo=reply.

That means Camel forces to uses CACHE_SESSION as the reply queue is considered a shared reply queue, and Camel uses a JMS Message selector to pickup the expected reply message based on correlation IDs. And for the JMS message selector to be updated, you need to re-create the consumer. And that is why you see the a consumer is removed in the logs. Its that reply consumer.

In Camel 2.9 onwards we introduced a replyToType option, which you can set to replyToType=Exclusive. And then the reply queue is considered exclusive, which means Camel uses CACHE_CONSUMER instead.

Comment: Aside upgrading to 2.9, how else can I go around this and ensure I get a reply?

Comment: What is the implication of re-using a correlation Id to send a request/reply message?

See line 4 & line 8 above.

Comment: I answered your question about the closed consumer. If you have other kind of questions then ask in a new Q